# <video> causes many requests *before being clicked*

Tags: iphone, html, html5-video

Even with preload disabled, the most simple `<video>` tag

```
<video src="video.mp4" preload="none"></video>
```

will cause **10** requests to the server *before being clicked*:

```
89.212.77.133 - - [01/Dec/2010:11:48:43 +0100] "GET /temp/html5-video-requests-test/one-noposter.html HTTP/1.1" 200 267 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone Simulator; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A400 Safari/6531.22.7"
89.212.77.133 - - [01/Dec/2010:11:48:43 +0100] "GET /temp/html5-video-requests-test/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 2 "-" "AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.8A400 (iPhone Simulator; U; CPU OS 4_0_2 like Mac OS X; en_us)"
89.212.77.133 - - [01/Dec/2010:11:48:43 +0100] "GET /temp/html5-video-requests-test/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 8621463 "-" "AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.8A400 (iPhone Simulator; U; CPU OS 4_0_2 like Mac OS X; en_us)"
89.212.77.133 - - [01/Dec/2010:11:48:43 +0100] "GET /temp/html5-video-requests-test/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 101783 "-" "AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.8A400 (iPhone Simulator; U; CPU OS 4_0_2 like Mac OS X; en_us)"
89.212.77.133 - - [01/Dec/2010:11:48:44 +0100] "GET /temp/html5-video-requests-test/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 8499743 "-" "AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.8A400 (iPhone Simulator; U; CPU OS 4_0_2 like Mac OS X; en_us)"
89.212.77.133 - - [01/Dec/2010:11:48:44 +0100] "GET /temp/html5-video-requests-test/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.8A400 (iPhone Simulator; U; CPU OS 4_0_2 like Mac OS X; en_us)"
89.212.77.133 - - [01/Dec/2010:11:48:44 +0100] "GET /temp/html5-video-requests-test/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 2 "-" "AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.8A400 (iPhone Simulator; U; CPU OS 4_0_2 like Mac OS X; en_us)"
89.212.77.133 - - [01/Dec/2010:11:48:44 +0100] "GET /temp/html5-video-requests-test/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 8621463 "-" "AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.8A400 (iPhone Simulator; U; CPU OS 4_0_2 like Mac OS X; en_us)"
89.212.77.133 - - [01/Dec/2010:11:48:44 +0100] "GET /temp/html5-video-requests-test/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 101783 "-" "AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.8A400 (iPhone Simulator; U; CPU OS 4_0_2 like Mac OS X; en_us)"
89.212.77.133 - - [01/Dec/2010:11:48:45 +0100] "GET /temp/html5-video-requests-test/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 8505535 "-" "AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.8A400 (iPhone Simulator; U; CPU OS 4_0_2 like Mac OS X; en_us)"
89.212.77.133 - - [01/Dec/2010:11:48:44 +0100] "GET /temp/html5-video-requests-test/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 8519680 "-" "AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.8A400 (iPhone Simulator; U; CPU OS 4_0_2 like Mac OS X; en_us)"
```

Setting a poster reduces this to poster + approx. 3 requests.

Since I have many videos on a page, I don't want the browser to make *any* requests until the video is clicked.

What more can I do besides set a poster and disable preload?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
<video preload="none">
    <source src="video.mp4" />
</video>
```

I'm very new to HTML5, so I'm not sure if my suggestion here is more or less identical to your code.

I know little to nothing on the server side of things. Where are you getting your data about the 10 requests? Looks like you're testing using the iPhone Simulator. Is this from the console log?

Found a reference to 206 Status here: [Notes on HTML5 Video and iPhone](http://jonathanstark.com/blog/2010/02/15/notes-on-html5-video-and-iphone/). Caveat is that it's over a year old.